# Nuget not generating binding redirect for weak named assemblies

Tags: c#, dll, deployment, nuget, strongname

I have been unable to find any documentation on this, but does nuget binding redirect generation only work for strong named assemblies? I have a handful of internal libraries that we have on our own nuget server that are all weak named, but on each publish to nuget a different version number is generated for the dll.

Because of the differing version number, a dependency that references that assembly will fail to load an assembly with a different version number than it was compiled against at runtime. So right now we are in the scenario where if we publish a new nuget to a common library, we have to manually publish all nuget packages that reference that common library(even though the change is backwards compatible). We are in the process of switching to strong naming everything, but currently due to legacy decisions nothing is strong named, so a workaround for now would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think NuGet support add binding-redirect to weak named assemblies. A document describing it is http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-3-unification-via.html.

A workaround may be adding an install.ps1 to the packages. So during package update/installation, the install.ps1 will add/modify the binding redirects on the configs.

Comment: Actually there is no such concept as "binding redirect for not-strongly-signed assemblies" in .Net, so even with script you can't make one. On other hand one should not have problem if latest version is already loaded as .Net ignores version comparison if it is not signed. Otherwise useful post.